# Probability, Expectation and Conditional

Tags: probability

Two life insurance policies, each with a death beneﬁt of 10,000 and a onetime premium of 500, are sold to a couple, one for each person. The policies will expire at the end of the tenth year. The probability that only the wife will survive at least ten years is 0.025, the probability that only the husband will survive at least ten years is 0.01, and the probability that both of them will survive at least ten years is 0.96 . What is the expected excess of premiums over claims, given that the husband survives at least ten years?

So here's what I did:

W : Woman will survive
H : Husband will survive

P(W) = 0.025
P(H) = 0.01
P(WH) = 0.96

We want to find P(W|H).

Okay so I know P(W|H) = P(WH)/P(H) = 96 which cannot be possible.

But using Bayes' Formula : P(WH)/[P(H|W)P(W) + P(H|W')P(W')] = 0.96/[0.96 + 0.01] = 0.98969 which makes sense as a probability.

So expected premiums over claims is 500 + 500 - (1 - 0.98969) * 10,000 = 896.91

My question is how come my first conditional probability formula gave a wacky answer, but Bayes' didn't...shouldn't they be equal?

Comment: Your events are poorly defined. If $W$ means "the event that the wife survives" then $P(W)\neq .025$ since that number refers to the probability that ONLY the wife survives.  Similarly for $H$.

Comment: You need to be very careful in assigning a meaning to $W$: is it that the woman *alone* will survive? That's given as $0.025$. But if it means that that the woman will survive (with or without her husband), *that* probability is $0.025 + 0.96$.